# Animate height change when the DataContext of an ItemsControl changes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` that binds to its `DataContext`. When the `DataContext` changes, I want the height change of `ItemsControl` animated. I tried to specify a `DataContextChanged` event for the `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="items" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LocationTemplate}" DataContextChanged="Items_DataContextChanged">
```

And in the handler, I tried to create a `DoubleAnimation` for height. However, I don't know how to specify `From` and `To` properties. Anyone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create the effect that (I think) you are after by wrapping the `ItemsControl` in a `Canvas`:

```
<Canvas x:Name="ClippingContainer" Background="Aquamarine" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ClipToBounds="True">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ICont" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SizeChanged="ItemsControl_SizeChanged"/>
</Canvas>
```

Then responding to the `ItemsControl.SizeChanged` event by animating the `Height` and `Width` properties of the parent `Canvas`.

```
private void ItemsControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    if (double.IsNaN(ClippingContainer.Height))
    {
        ClippingContainer.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
    }
    else
    {
        ClippingContainer.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, new DoubleAnimation(e.NewSize.Height, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))));
    }
    if (double.IsNaN(ClippingContainer.Width))
    {
        ClippingContainer.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
    }
    else
    {
        ClippingContainer.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, new DoubleAnimation(e.NewSize.Width, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))));
    }
}
```

NOTE: This could easily be converted into its own `UserControl`. In doing so, you could then override the `MeasureOverride` and force a layout pass to redraw any parent layout container that the animated `ItemsControl` belongs to.

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void MyItemsControl_DataContextChanged(object Sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, New DoubleAnimation(500.0, New Duration(Timespan.FromMilliseconds(500))));
}
```

Comment: Remember, if the From property of the DoubelAnimation is not specified, it will animate from the current value....which in many cases is the desired behavior (e.g. prevents a "jumping" effect if another animation is in progress or another value has effected the animated property)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to hardcode the toValue either, because the control may grow or shrink depending on how many items inside. Is there any way that I can get the actual height for the toValue?

Comment: If you give more specifics about what you are trying to accomplish, I am happy to try and help further. :)

Comment: I tried DesiredSize.Height, but it just keeps growing by 10px each time no matter how items change...

Comment: Sure! Thanks, XamlZealot. Basically, I have an ItemsControl bound to its DataContext. Its DataContext is changed programmatically when a button is clicked. Its ItemsPanelTemplate is a UniformGrid with only 1 column. Right now, if I click the button to change the DataContext, the ItemsControl changes abruptly. I want to add a transition to the change, namely expanding/shrinking the height of ItemsControl when its DataContext changes.

Comment: Maybe what you are trying to do is better accomplished in the SizeChanged event, not the DataContextChanged. If you utilize the SizeChangedHandler, you can handle the sizechanged event, then animate to the new value.

Comment: That caused an infinte loop: An infinite loop appears to have resulted from repeatedly invalidating the TimeManager during the Layout/Render process.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19182/discussion-between-xamlzealot-and-uni)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Grid_SizeChanged_1(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation(e.NewSize.Height, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))));
}
```